# How to bind a value in select box which doesn't present in content using Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of values in content array of Ember.Select. The selected value may or may not be present in the content. But have to show the selected value if doesn't present in content.

For more details check this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guvar/1/edit)

In this if I click on "setColorWithNewValue", it sets the colorObj with new value that doesn't present in colorArray. When I click on "alertValue" button it shows the value in ColorObj but it doesn't selected in select box.

Answer (score 1):

The selected object needs to be in the selection too.

When you call `setColorWithNewValue`, just push the new object to `colorsArray` and set the reference to `colorObj`.

```
setColorWithNewValue: function() {
    var newObject = { 'name': 'White', 'value': '5'};
    this.get('colorsArray').push(newObject);
    this.set('colorObj', newObject);
}
```

or without changing the `colorsArray`

```
mergedArray: function(){
    var arr = new Ember.A(this.get('colorsArray'));
    arr.push(this.get('colorObj'));
    return arr;
}.property('colorObj', 'colorsArray.@each')
```

And pass merged array to the select field.

Also look into `Ember.Array` and `Ember.Object`. Ember extends native Objects and Arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But in my case, i don't want to change my content array. Any work arounds for that?

Comment: Yes, create a new property function where you merge colorsArray and colorsObject. And pass it instead of colorsArray to the select field.

Comment: Thanks @medokin. And one more small question, is there any other way to bind a value in select box which is not present in content.ie without update the value in content array which is passed to Ember.Select?

Comment: I think that it is not possible with embers selectView, but you can always write your own component to accomplish it.